# root_partition.tar.gz 1.3GB -> 140GB+ when unzipped

Tags: ubuntu, tar, root

I asked a friend to make a full backup of a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server and he created this 1.3GB root_partition.tar.gz file on the server itself, but when I try to extract it on Windows 10 with 7-Zip to check what's inside, the size goes beyond 140Gb and I run out of disk space. What is going on and how can I see the content?

Edit: `du -h -d 1 / ?` says 4.4GB are used and the server has 2x 136GB HDD in RAID 1 i think. I dont know what command he used, but if I extract in a partition with more than 136GB could it work?

Comment: There could be, really, 140GB of content in that Ubuntu root. so let's check. 1) Exactly what command, with all parameters and switches, did he use to generate the tar.gz file? 2) On that Ubuntu system what appears when he runs `du -h -d 1 /` ? Please click [edit] here and add the results to your question; please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: The data was very easy to compress. I presume the root partition itself was gzipped – including all unused space. The easiest way to resolve this probably is buying additional storage space.

Comment: "and how can I see the content?" -- that is an MS-Windows question if you are doing it on MS-Windows. On Gnu (Ubuntu etc) you can stream the data, and see what is inside.

Comment: What is the size of thendecompressed `tar` archive? If it is 140GB, it could be due to including mounted other filesystems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be due to him tar gzipping things like `/proc/kcore` (which is entire system memory) and other things in `/proc` and `/dev`. Which take no space in linux (as they are virtual FSes), and have 0 size when compressed, but when you untar them, they probably take one filesystem block each.

I would suggest installing [Windows linux subsystem](https://www.windowscentral.com/install-windows-subsystem-linux-windows-10).

And using something like `tar tzvf root_partition.tar.gz` to look inside. And then extract specific files by doing `tar xzvf root_partition.tar.gz /home/some_directory_or_file`

Comment: Yes I remember that during compression it got stuck on `/proc/kcore` for a long time so it's definitely in there. If extracted in a linux system I wouldnt have the same problem (space, time consuming) ?

Comment: You may, cause you will copy the file to different location, but - you can just use something like this:
`tar xzvf root_partition.tar.gz --exclude=proc/* --exclude=dev/*` this should take care of this.

Comment: And in future I would strongly advise adding `--exclude /proc --exclude=/dev` to avoid packing stuff like that :)

Comment: I found out he should have used `--exclude` when reading about restore. I am trying with the command you gave and come back with the result

Comment: Extracting through Linux seems to avoid the space requirement but it still needs a long time to process all the information. In my case I wasnt lucky because the compression maybe was interrupted. I get `gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive`. I will start another question on how to to do it again

Comment: I posted another question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/567754/restoring-root-partition-tar-gz about restore