# restoring root_partition.tar.gz

Tags: tar, root

I used `tar -cvpzf root_partition.tar.gz --exclude=/root_partition.tar.gz --one-file-system /` on a remote system following the information here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR and I am trying to restore `root_partition.tar.gz` to a machine in VMware on my computer (same Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).
How do you replace the content of `root` while the machine is running ? Actually I more interested in Apache and MySQL on the old machine so I probably need just a few folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just restoring the tar to pull data out and/or investigate, you don't need to restore it in the same place it was on the original system.

```
tar -C /path/to/restore/dir -xf /path/to/archive
```

Comment: I would like to boot from the restored archive. I tried `cd /` `sudo tar -C root_partition.tar.gz -xf /` in the Ubuntu VM I had installed, but old and information seemed to be mixing

Comment: Of course.  If you just extract a tar file over top of your existing directories, it will only replace the files it has in the tar, not remove your other files or data.  Create a blank volume, set up the partitions, and untar onto the blank volume.  Then chroot over to the blank volume and install the boot loader in order to boot from that volume.  You'll also have to make sure all your partitions on the old system are accounted for on the new volume and that you have archives of those as well.  Doing a full-up restore is a lot more involved than just creating and extracing a tar archive.